# jdeps can't print-module-deps due to a MultiReleaseException

Tags: java, javafx, java-platform-module-system, java-17, jdeps

We have a JavaFX based application which is **not** modularized (there are reasons, a legacy library is involved) but we build an custom runtime using `jdeps` and `jlink`.

We've recently rewritten the app and added a couple of new dependencies, as well as removing others. Now the script that is building the application suddenly stopped working during the `jdeps` call.

**Note:** This is happening on Linux – I've yet to test other OS'ses, but I don't expect another result.

When the script calls

```
~/path/to/jdk/bin/jdeps -q --multi-release 11 --ignore-missing-deps --print-module-deps --class-path ~/path/to/app/target/package/libs/* target/classes/ch/cnlab/uxtest/MainKt.class
```

the result is always

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.tools.jdeps.MultiReleaseException
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DependencyFinder.waitForTasksCompleted(DependencyFinder.java:271)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DependencyFinder.parse(DependencyFinder.java:133)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DepsAnalyzer.transitiveArchiveDeps(DepsAnalyzer.java:217)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DepsAnalyzer.run(DepsAnalyzer.java:138)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ModuleExportsAnalyzer.run(ModuleExportsAnalyzer.java:74)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask$ListModuleDeps.run(JdepsTask.java:1047)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:574)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:533)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.tools.jdeps.MultiReleaseException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DependencyFinder.waitForTasksCompleted(DependencyFinder.java:267)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.jdeps.MultiReleaseException
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.VersionHelper.add(VersionHelper.java:62)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ClassFileReader$JarFileReader.readClassFile(ClassFileReader.java:360)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ClassFileReader$JarFileIterator.hasNext(ClassFileReader.java:402)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DependencyFinder.lambda$parse$5(DependencyFinder.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I couldn't find much in regards to this specific exception and everything I've found so far was not applicable to our situation.

To not wait as long as the build takes to reach this point, I've let the program print out the command before it gets executed and use it on a terminal. Then it get's a bit weirder:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.slf4j not found, required by com.dlsc.gmapsfx
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:893)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:192)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:141)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:421)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:255)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration$Builder.build(JdepsConfiguration.java:564)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.buildConfig(JdepsTask.java:603)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:557)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:533)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

Why of all sudden to I get a different exception? Which one is correct now? I have no clue.
Fact is, the jar containing `org.slf4j` only has the automatic module name.

I really have have no idea, what I should do with little information... If someone else can point to something, I'd be glad.

Thanks,
Daniel

**PS:** The following code prints the command and executes it:

```sh
echo "detecting required modules"
CMD="$JDK/bin/jdeps -q --multi-release ${JAVA_VERSION} --ignore-missing-deps --print-module-deps --class-path ${OUT_LIBS}/* ${MAIN_CLASS_FILE}"; echo "$CMD"
detected_modules=$("$JDK"/bin/jdeps -q \
  --multi-release ${JAVA_VERSION} \
  --ignore-missing-deps \
  --print-module-deps \
  --class-path "${OUT_LIBS}/*" \
    "${MAIN_CLASS_FILE}") || exit
echo "detected modules: ${detected_modules}"
```

They really seem to create different result...

**PPS:** If I remove the `--multi-release` part, I get a different error, that `jackson` is multi-release, but I need to specify what I want...

```
Error: jackson-core-2.13.0.jar is a multi-release jar file but --multi-release option is not set
```

---

**Edit #1**

In the pom file, we have the following deps

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
    <version>${use.javafx.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>${use.javafx.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>${use.javafx.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>${use.javafx.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
    <version>${use.javafx.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlinx.coroutines.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlinx.coroutines.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.insert-koin</groupId>
    <artifactId>koin-core-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>${koin.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.insert-koin</groupId>
    <artifactId>koin-test-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>${koin.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
    <version>${simplexml.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
    <version>${proguard.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
    <artifactId>ikonli-materialdesign2-pack</artifactId>
    <version>${ikonli.mdi2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
    <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
    <version>${ikonli.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
    <version>${controlsfx.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dlsc</groupId>
    <artifactId>GMapsFX</artifactId>
    <version>${gmapfx.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${sqlite.jdbc.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- some custom deps from our company -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.conscrypt</groupId>
    <artifactId>conscrypt-openjdk</artifactId>
    <version>${conscrypt.version}</version>
    <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Resulting in the following JAR files (minus our own):

```
annotations-13.0.jar
apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar
conscrypt-openjdk-2.5.2-linux-x86_64.jar
controlsfx-11.1.0.jar
GMapsFX-11.0.2.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
ikonli-core-12.2.0.jar
ikonli-javafx-12.2.0.jar
ikonli-materialdesign2-pack-12.2.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.13.0.jar
jackson-core-2.13.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar
jackson-module-kotlin-2.13.0.jar
jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar
jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar
jaxb-impl-2.3.3.jar
junit-4.12.jar
junit-jupiter-api-5.8.1.jar
junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar
junit-platform-commons-1.8.1.jar
junit-platform-engine-1.8.1.jar
koin-core-jvm-3.1.3.jar
koin-test-jvm-3.1.3.jar
kotlin-reflect-1.5.31.jar
kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar
kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.30.jar
kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.31.jar
kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31.jar
kotlin-test-1.5.31.jar
kotlin-test-annotations-common-1.5.30.jar
kotlin-test-common-1.5.30.jar
kotlin-test-junit-1.5.31.jar
kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.5.2.jar
kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar
kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8-1.5.2.jar
log4j-api-2.14.1.jar
log4j-core-2.14.1.jar
log4j-web-2.14.1.jar
logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
logback-core-1.2.3.jar
okhttp-4.9.2.jar
okio-2.8.0.jar
opentest4j-1.2.0.jar
proguard-base-6.2.2.jar
simple-xml-2.7.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.29.jar
sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar
stax-1.2.0.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar
```

The Java version in use is **Bell Soft's Full Liberica JDK 17**, we used all recent versions since 14 or 15 where it worked well **prior** to the rebuild of the UI.

---

**edit #2:**

The result of

```
mvn compile org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:resolve -DexcludeTransitive
```

is

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.0:compile -- module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
[INFO]    com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:4.9.2:compile -- module okhttp3 [auto]
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.0:compile -- module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation
[INFO]    org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:jar:17.0.1:compile -- module javafx.fxmlEmpty [auto]
[INFO]    org.openjfx:javafx-web:jar:17.0.1:compile -- module javafx.webEmpty [auto]
[INFO]    org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.5.31:compile -- module kotlin.stdlib.jdk8
[INFO]    io.insert-koin:koin-core-jvm:jar:3.1.3:compile -- module koin.core.jvm (auto)
[INFO]    org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:jar:1.5.31:test -- module kotlin.test.junit
[INFO]    org.simpleframework:simple-xml:jar:2.7.1:compile -- module simple.xml [auto]
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.14.1:compile -- module org.apache.logging.log4j.core [auto]
[INFO]    io.insert-koin:koin-test-jvm:jar:3.1.3:compile -- module koin.test.jvm (auto)
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.1:test -- module org.junit.jupiter.engine
[INFO]    org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.36.0.3:compile -- module org.xerial.sqlitejdbc [auto]
[INFO]    net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:jar:6.2.2:runtime -- module proguard.base (auto)
[INFO]    org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:17.0.1:compile -- module javafx.graphicsEmpty [auto]
[INFO]    org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:jar:1.5.2:compile -- module kotlinx.coroutines.core (auto)
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.14.1:compile -- module org.apache.logging.log4j.web [auto]
[INFO]    ch.<ourgroup>:<our-artifact>:1.8.8:compile -- module <our-lib> (auto)
[INFO]    org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:17.0.1:compile -- module javafx.controlsEmpty [auto]
[INFO]    org.controlsfx:controlsfx:jar:11.1.0:compile -- module org.controlsfx.controls
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.0:compile -- module com.fasterxml.jackson.core
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:jar:2.13.0:compile -- module com.fasterxml.jackson.kotlin
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile -- module org.apache.logging.log4j
[INFO]    org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:17.0.1:compile -- module javafx.baseEmpty [auto]
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.1:test -- module org.junit.jupiter.api
[INFO]    org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:jar:12.2.0:compile -- module org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx
[INFO]    com.dlsc:GMapsFX:jar:11.0.2:compile -- module com.dlsc.gmapsfx
[INFO]    org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:jar:1.5.31:compile -- module kotlin.reflect
[INFO]    org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:jar:1.5.2:compile -- module kotlinx.coroutines.jdk8 (auto)
[INFO]    org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-materialdesign2-pack:jar:12.2.0:compile -- module org.kordamp.ikonli.materialdesign2
[INFO]    org.conscrypt:conscrypt-openjdk:jar:linux-x86_64:2.5.2:compile -- module org.conscrypt [auto]
```

Comment: Can you share a list of all JAR files (or/and their Maven coordinates) being on the class path? Or is the entire app and its build configuration available online?

Comment: Which jdeps version is running here? What does `~/path/to/jdk/bin/java -version` print?

Comment: I can certainly share the jar file, but the app itself is not open source, gimme a second and I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thanks for listing them -- will check if they are listed as "suspicious" here https://github.com/sormuras/modules#suspicious-artifacts

One more thing: what does "mvn compile org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:resolve -DexcludeTransitive" print?

Comment: Looking at the jdeps source for the first error: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/jdk.jdeps/share/classes/com/sun/tools/jdeps/VersionHelper.java#L60 it should be printing a message like: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/jdk.jdeps/share/classes/com/sun/tools/jdeps/resources/jdeps.properties#L246 i.e. it seems like it's complaining that the same class has multiple versions. But, that should be fine I think...

Comment: @JornVernee thanks for looking into it as well. One question might be: Why doesn't jdeps print the message in the stack trace. That probably would help a bit. Is there a way to make the command more verbose (the option seem to do something else)?

Comment: Note: When I use the one-line command (instead of the multi-line one) and remove the dependency to gmapfx, I'm greeted with the same error, but for junit. Since junit makes no sense to keep in the final build, I filtered them out. Now I'm back with the not-so-helpful MultiReleaseException. Once again I'm back to ... 

Comment: I think the error message not being printed correctly is a bug, and I've filed [JDK-8277123](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8277123) for it. Maybe you could find out which jar file it's failing on? (e.g. try running all jars through jdeps one by one), and then check what is contained in `META-INF/versions` in the failing jar. I think that would help to create a smaller reproducer.

Comment: Okay, the exception you are seeing is a bug as well, likely caused by 2 different jar files having a module-info.class file in a different versioned directory (or just a class with the same name, but that seems less likely) [JDK-8277165](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8277165). The reason it's sometimes not happening is likely because there's a data race going on as well [JDK-8277166](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8277166).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: These issues have been fixed, and a patched version of `jdeps` is available as part of the early access build for JDK 18 at: http://jdk.java.net/18/ (starting from build 26)

---

Turning my comments into an answer. There seem to be 3 bugs going on here:

1. The `MultiReleaseException` seems to be because `jdeps` can not handle classes in different jars that have the same name, such as `module-info.class`, but are stored in a different `META-INF/versions/xxx` directory. ([JDK-8277165](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8277165))
2. The fact that this exception is sometimes suddenly not occuring seems to be the result of a race condition in the code that checks for the above; classes of the same name having multiple versions. ([JDK-8277166](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8277166))
3. The `MultiReleaseException` is missing it's exception message since it's thrown as part of an asynchronous task, which wraps it in an `ExecutionException`, which then leads to `jdeps` not reporting the exception correctly. ([JDK-8277123](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8277123))

As for a workaround, I don't think there's a good one at this point, except maybe for editing all the jars on the class path so that they put the `module-info.class` in the same `META-INF/versions/xxx` directory (but, this might have other consequences as well, so you probably don't want to run with the edited jars, and only use them for `jdeps`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort and for raising the issues. I still could try to test each JAR as you suggested, but for now I've returned to the simplest approach: I `jlink` a tailored runtime based on a fix list of modules. This is not ideal, since it may miss modules or contain too much, but is OK for the moment. But I will get back to your suggestion, as soon as we are required to go live with the application.